# Alternative excercise to biking

Tags: training, health

Are there any alternative exercise to biking while it's raining?

I have been fortunate enough to solve my insomnia with biking...something with it seems to connect and works well to solve my ages old problem of sleep.

The part that helps me most is climbing hills, not so much the flat parts.

Jogging, walking, etc. somehow DO NOT seem to have the same effect in my case.

I am wondering what I will do when winter comes in and it  starts raining... any suggestions other than buying a costly stationary bike?

Comment: Where/what climate do you live in? People ride all year around in many parts of the world.

Comment: I am in California, I am ok with cold weather in winter, I am concerned when it rains.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because IT does not appear to be about bicycles within the scope defined in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: What’s the problem with cycling in the rain? You just have to gather the willpower and head out there. After you’ve warmed up it’s lots of fun. I could swear bad weather increases adrenaline and testosterone production :D

Comment: When it rains, you get wet.  You do have to be concerned with the temperature -- much below about 50f and you can get badly chilled if you don't have raingear that blocks the wind (and, alas, with the raingear you can overheat, so it's a little tricky).  And if the temp, while raining, dips down to 40f or so you need to do something to keep your feet warm.

Comment: Raingear is a controversial topic. In my opinion it’s unnecessary or actually disadvantageous for excercise with some intensity. A softshell jacket and some windstopper bibtights should be enough. Overshoes and gloves are important.

Comment: Assuming it actually does rain here in CA this winter... (I kid, I kid) Like Michael said, cycling in the rain *can* be fun. & as OrioIMP mentioned, you may consider a trainer stand. Upper body, personally I go to an indoor rock climbing gym & do bouldering for an hour or two. If you enjoy problem solving & are persistent it may be worth a try (more engaging than lifting weights or something).

Comment: On non-biking days I like to work on non-biking muscles. Push ups, pull ups, sit ups, planks - mostly upper body and core. You can build up a whole routine to complement biking's aerobic/legs focus.

Comment: Kettlebell swinging? It trains aerobic system and also resistance, you hit legs and back in a similar way to cycling,  (and whole body if wanted) there are lots of variations, and the kettlebell is cheap and will survive you unless volcano lava melts it.

Answer (score 2):

You can train inside your house with a trainer stand. Is quite cheap compared to stationary bike and it can be stored more easily.